# Where can I get a visa for Brazil in Texas?

Tags: visas, brazil, texas

So I'm going to Brazil in March and I have no idea where one gets a visa. Do you have to go to a consulate, or a courthouse like where you get a passport? I'm in the Dallas area, so any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, depending on the country, an embassy or consulate is where you'd go to, in order to obtain a visa.

In your case, the nearest (that I can find) is the [Brazilian Consulate in Houston, Texas](http://www.brazil-help.com/brazil-emb-consul.htm#Houston).

> 1233 West Loop South,
>
> Park Tower North, Suite 1150
>
> Houston, TX  77027
>
> (713) 961-3063/64/65 Fax: (713) 961-3070
>
> E-mail:
> consbras@brazilhouston.org

So they'd be your most likely best bet for first point of call.

For a rough idea of the documentation you'll need to apply for your visa, have a look at the [Consulate General of Brazil in Miami's website](http://miami.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/tourist.xml) - they have a solid wall of information which will be of great use.

If you're really worried about the process, your travel agent would be able to help out with the whole thing. If you don't have a travel agent, don't worry, really, many of us apply for visas all the time, and while the wall of documents required sounds scary, as long as you follow the steps it's actually pretty straightforward.  Note that according to the Miami website, it can take 10-45 days to process depending on the method taken, so given you are travelling in March, I'd get the ball moving on the whole process pretty soon.

Comment: Yes, most of the consulates in Texas are in Houston (which is the largest metro area)!  Even though Austin is the state capitol, and is a pretty big and major city in itself, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel like taking a road trip, there are a number of companies that can request the visa on your behalf (for a fee).

I initially found a company called China Visa Service Center that does this when preparing for my [trip to China](/a/1527/82) (although from the name, you can probably guess that they only do Chinese visas).

I have also used VisaHQ (for my Paraguay visa) and I was particularly impressed with their level of service (esp. because you can track your request online).

As an example, VisaHQ also can help with [Brazilian visas](http://brazil.visahq.com/) (link applies to US citizens).

Comment: Ah, interesting. I have no problem doing paperwork myself, but I'll keep this in mind. Thanks!